# R, Install "RMySQL" On MAC - curl: (23) Failed writing body

Tags: mysql, r, osx-elcapitan, rmysql

I'm attempting to install the RMySQL package in R using a MAC running OS X El Capitan but receive errors that I haven't seen before.  See below:

[image]

MySQL and Curl are installed.  I've tried a few things such as uninstalling and re-installing MySQL and running installing the package manually via the terminal.  Any advice or assistance would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like curl can't write to the folder; check the permissions of whatever folder `.libPaths()` returns. That would cause an error for any package install, though, so that may not be it.

Comment: This package installed randomly.  I literally had to do something else for a couple of hours and came back - poof it worked.  Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proxy setting on your machine? It seems an Internet connection problem. If you have proxy, you can set in R by :

```
>Sys.setenv(http_proxy="url")
>Sys.setenv(https_proxy="url")
```